# flutter: how are dependencies on inherited widgets discovered?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently reading the example code of the [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider#-example-tab-) package:

```
// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class Counter with ChangeNotifier {
  int _count = 0;
  int get count => _count;

  void increment() {
    _count++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (_) => Counter()),
      ],
      child: Consumer<Counter>(
        builder: (context, counter, _) {
          return MaterialApp(
            supportedLocales: const [Locale('en')],
            localizationsDelegates: [
              DefaultMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
              DefaultWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
              _ExampleLocalizationsDelegate(counter.count),
            ],
            home: const MyHomePage(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ExampleLocalizations {
  static ExampleLocalizations of(BuildContext context) =>
      Localizations.of<ExampleLocalizations>(context, ExampleLocalizations);

  const ExampleLocalizations(this._count);

  final int _count;

  String get title => 'Tapped $_count times';
}

class _ExampleLocalizationsDelegate
    extends LocalizationsDelegate<ExampleLocalizations> {
  const _ExampleLocalizationsDelegate(this.count);

  final int count;

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) => locale.languageCode == 'en';

  @override
  Future<ExampleLocalizations> load(Locale locale) =>
      SynchronousFuture(ExampleLocalizations(count));

  @override
  bool shouldReload(_ExampleLocalizationsDelegate old) => old.count != count;
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Title()),
      body: const Center(child: CounterLabel()),
      floatingActionButton: const IncrementCounterButton(),
    );
  }
}

class IncrementCounterButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const IncrementCounterButton({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: Provider.of<Counter>(context).increment,
      tooltip: 'Increment',
      child: const Icon(Icons.add),
    );
  }
}

class CounterLabel extends StatelessWidget {
  const CounterLabel({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final counter = Provider.of<Counter>(context);
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        const Text(
          'You have pushed the button this many times:',
        ),
        Text(
          '${counter.count}',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Title extends StatelessWidget {
  const Title({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(ExampleLocalizations.of(context).title);
  }
}
```

When the user presses the `FloatingRadioButton` within `IncrementCounterButton`, `build()` is called on `CounterLabel` and `IncrementCounterButton`.

They both depend on an inherited widget, which is updated.
How does flutter discover this dependency?

I assume that the `BuildContext` is modified by the call to `Provider.of<>()`.
Is this why we add the `IncrementCounterButton`, which has no functionality on its own?
Just to move the call to `Provider.of<>()` outside of its bigger parent widget, which would be more expensive to rebuild?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binding widget an InheritedWidget and its consumers is created through `BuildContext`.

Consider the following InheritedWidget:

```dart
class Foo extends InheritedWidget {}
```

Then the descendants of `Foo` can subscribe to it by calling:

```dart
BuildContext context
context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(Foo);
```

It's worth noting that a widget can obtain the InheritedWidget *without* subscribing to it, by instead doing:

```dart
BuildContext context
context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(Foo);
```

---

This call is usually performed internally by the `.of(context)` pattern.

In the case of `provider`, that subscription is done by calling `Provider.of<T>(context)`.

`provider` also exposes an optional argument to purposefully *not* subscribe to the inherited widget:

```
T value = Provider.of<T>(context, listen: false);
```